# Rigorous proof of the bounds of $f(x) = (x-2)/x(x-3)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I need to prove that for the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x\,(x-3)}, \qquad x \in (0,3)$$
we have $-\infty \leq f(x) \leq +\infty$.

This statement follows from the asymptotes at $x=0$ and $x=3$. I understand this intuitively, but it’s not enough to write $-\infty \leq f(x) \leq +\infty$ just from the limits $\lim_{x \to 3^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$.

I need to be more precise with the definitions. Can you suggest how to prove this correctly for a calculus course? I just need the general mindset, or a clue about how to prove this case.

Comment: Note that for every real function holds $ -\infty \le f(x)\le \infty$

Comment: If you want to avoid all of the manipulation given below you could try to show that the function achieves arbitrarily large values, and then appeal to the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $f(x)=k$ gives you
$$\frac{x-2}{x(x-3)}=k\iff x(x-3)k=x-2\iff kx^2+(-3k-1)x+2=0.$$
If $k=0$, then $x=2$. In the following, suppose that $k\not=0$.

Now note that the discriminant will be
$$D=(-3k-1)^2-4k\cdot 2=9\left(k-\frac 19\right)^2+\frac 89\gt 0$$

Also, the following holds for $k\not =0$ :
$$0\lt x=\frac{3k+1-\sqrt{D}}{2k}\lt 3\tag1$$

To see this, let us separate it into cases :

When $k\gt 0$, we have
$$(1)\iff 0\lt 3k+1-\sqrt D\lt 6k\iff -3k+1\lt \sqrt D\lt 3k+1.$$
Now if $-3k+1\le 0$, then the left inequality holds. So, when $-3k+1\gt 0\iff 0\lt k\lt 1/3$, 
$$-3k+1\lt \sqrt D\iff (-3k+1)^2\lt D\iff -6k\lt -2k\iff k\gt 0.$$ Also, when $k\gt 0$, since $3k+1\gt 0$,$$\sqrt D\lt 3k+1\iff D\lt (3k+1)^2\iff -2k\lt 6k\iff k\gt 0.$$

You can see $(1)$ holds for $k\lt 0$ in the same way as above.

Hence, we now know that 
$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x(x-3)}=k$$
has at least one solution $0\lt x\lt 3$ for any $k\in\mathbb R$.

This leads that $f(x)$ can be any real number for $0\lt x\lt 3$.

Comment: it's very impressive. I don't undestamd how you got the"less then 3. there is any general mindset to solve it with tools of calculus? thank you very much.

Comment: @user3708158: I added a bit. Take a look.